# Prove logical equivalence without a truth table

Tags: logic

I came across a problem that I'm stuck at. It's about basic logic.

Here is the problem:

Prove that $(P \land R) \Rightarrow (\sim Q)$ is logically equivalent to $\sim (P \land ( Q \land R))$ without making a truth table.

Comment: Basically, you have to derive $\vdash\phi\leftrightarrow\psi$. If you give more information on what you've tried and the inference rules you're allowed, people can give you more than vague hints

Comment: Hint: $P\implies Q \iff (\sim P)\lor Q$

Comment: Can you use that $a \implies b \equiv \neg a \lor b$?

Comment: I don't know if I'm just stupid and don't know logic, but what is $R$?

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide it's just an input, just like P and Q . I have 3 inputs P, R and Q

Comment: @David it's not in the first statement though

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide what do you mean ?

Comment: @David the statements aren't logically equivalent when P is true, Q is true, and R is false

Comment: @Ender_The_Xenocide If R is false then P^R are false. If the first part of an IF statement is false, then the statement is always true. If False => X is always True, no matter what X is. The right statement is also True if R is false since you have ~(False) at the end, which is True.

Comment: @David That $R$ was a $Q$ before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've solved it

$(P \land Q) \Rightarrow (\sim Q) \equiv \sim ( P \land R ) \lor (\sim Q) \equiv (\sim P) \lor (\sim R) \lor (\sim Q) \equiv \sim(P \land Q \land R) $

Comment: This should be an edit to your question, adding the tag solution-verification

Comment: Where is $R$ coming from???? There is no $R$ in the far left.